# C array starts reading after the fourth element

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a c program that turns command line arguments into numbers. Now i want those numbers to be stored in an array. The problem is when i print out those elements in the array something weird happens. The array is printed starting at the sixth element.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, num, randint, arrCount = 0;
    int arrList[1000] = {0};

    for(i=1; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; ++j)
        {
            if (argv[i][j] >= 'A' && argv[i][j] <= 'Z')
            {
                num = argv[i][j] - 'A';
                //arrList[j] = num;
            }
            else if (argv[i][j] >= 'a' && argv[i][j] <= 'z')
            {
                num = argv[i][j] - 'a';
                //arrList[j] = num;
            }
            num = num + '0' - 47;
            arrList[j] = num;
            arrCount++;
            printf("%d ", num);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<arrCount; i++)
    {
         printf("%d ", arrList[i]);
    }
}
```

The command that i run to test is:

```
./encript Hello World
```

The output:

```
8 5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12 4 
23 15 18 12 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

As you an see the array is printing starting at the sixth element of the array and i can figure out why it is doing that. The extra zeros are because the array is printing elements in that array that do not actually exist. The most i can figure is that the arrCount which is used to find how many elements are needed to be printed is messed up. 
I been looking at this for far too long and i can not figure out what is wrong here even though it is most likely obvious.

Comment: `arrList[j] = num;arrCount++;` --> `arrList[arrCount++] = num;` ?

Comment: Your code only knows how to deal with a single word as an argument, since every words overrides the last one, perhaps instead of writing to arrList[j], you should write to arrList[arrCount]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fill `arrList` like this:

```
arrList[j] = num;
```

But `j` restarts at 0 for each command line argument, i.e. the results of `World` overwrite the results of `Hello`. You should store into `arrList[arrCount]` instead because `arrCount` increases across all arguments.